# Updating value of PHP.ini

Tags: configuration, upload, php

I have PHP.ini located at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and Loaded Configuration File :  `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

I have changed value of PHP.ini using root user to the following

```
php5_value upload_max_filesize = 24M
php5_value post_max_size = 32M
php5_value memory_limit = 32M
```

Restarted web services. all values are updated into the php.ini. But does not take effects in **phpinfo();**

Any idea what i am missing to config it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 24M
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Your PHP settings limit the maximum file size per upload to limited MB.
Depending on your server environment, these settings may be changed in the system-wide php.ini file.

Comment: Error , Files are not executing

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the lines into `.htaccess` also.

Answer (score 0):

try setting these inside your code using

```
ini_set('php5_value upload_max_filesize', '24M');
```

Then see it impact

Comment: did you check your apache config